Software to fake system specs
Its a long shot but is there free software available that I can use to trick a game into thinking i have the minimum system requirements to run.
The requirements are a 2060 and i79700 I have a 1070ti and i78700 and I am confident I can run it.
When I launch the game it does a check to make sure my hardware is to the minimum requirements but I do not pass. I would love bypass this check or emulate/trick the check to think that I am using other hardware.
Thanks,
Luke.

This is probably not a good idea; if the game works at all, the performance is likely to be sub-par, and if it's on-line, you're likely to be at a significant disadvantage due to the inferior performance.

No. Games use Windows APIs for that purpose, you'd need to override low level APIs, which is not anyone should ever even attempt to do. And your model is actually far from the minimum requirement. This is a waste of time to look into any further.

@Destroy666 While I can't say that OP's question is any practical, their specs are actually pretty similar to the game's supposed required specs. Though I am curious what kind of game would limit its requirements to that of a 20 series GPU, unless it requires some newer api...?
